# How to schedule a Jenkins job every hour at 20 minute

Tags: jenkins, build, cron

I need to schedule a Jenkins job each 20 minute for every hour meaning
(eg. 00:20, 01:20, 02:20, 03:20, etc.)

What I got now is:

`H * * * *` is running for every hour

`H/20 * * * *` is running every 20 minutes (each XX:20)

What is the right Cron expression for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Order is:
minute
hour
day of month
month
day of week


20 * * * *
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

Check it here
https://crontab.guru/#20_*_*_*_*